# SPA application built on asp.net mvc not responsive on mobile tablet

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, responsive-design, single-page-application, tablet

I have a SPA application built on asp.net mvc framework which works fine on all across all browsers , however it is not reponsive on a mobile tablet. How can I make it responsive on a mobile tablet? I came across this link  https://auth0.com/blog/2015/12/08/converting-your-web-app-to-mobile/
 however I am not sure if this will do the trick